# Manifold Developer user guide

Tags: gis, manifold

Is there a developer guide for Manifold System?
In their [site](http://www.manifold.net) i didn't find a beginners guide ,only a user guide and some samples.
I'm mostly interested in google map development through manifold.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information on the documents up on the website, but generally it takes a bit of digging to find out what you may need to know.  There is no developer guide as such.

The [Manifold GIS forum](http://www.georeference.org/forum/) is very helpful for questions and where I would suggest going if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

There is the "Programming Reference" section in the manual:

http://www.georeference.org/doc/manifold.htm#programming_reference.htm

That includes the Scripting Reference page, and various pages for API objects, constants and so on.

Answer (score 2):

there is also a manifold training video put out by www.gisadvisor.com that actaully shows you how to program the object model.  While its VBScript in its teaching, it does give you a good handle on the object model, and the general way in which you do scripting and programming in Manifold.